# How to calculate Coarse & Fine Carrier freqeuncy Offset using Short and Long training Preamble respectively! Equations not understood

Tags: phase, ofdm

I am transmitting an OFDM signal. According to 802.11a Standards, I am using Short and long training Preamble each has length of 160 samples for time and frequency synchronization.

According to [Essam Sourour, Hussein El-Ghoroury and Dale McNeill: Frequency Offset Estimation and Correction](https://openofdm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_downloads/vtc04_freq_offset.pdf).

Equations no. 4 and 5 for coarse and fine frequency offset estimation are not clear enough for me.

[image]

I have shared a shot of this paper page 3.
What is $S_m^*$ and the 2nd $S_m$!

Based on my understanding, I have performed equation (4) in matlab as follows (I basically did simulation by adding some AWGN noise and phase shift of -120 degrees ):

```
PhiST= angle( sum( conj(STSPreamble_Tx_80(1:64)) .* STSPreamble_Rx_80(17:end)) ) ./16;   ....eq4
PhiSTDeg=PhiST*180/pi
```

In the above code, I have multiplied the conjugate of the first 64 samples (1:64) of the known 80-samples-ST Preamble (extracted from the known 160-samples-ST preamble) with the 64-samples (17:80) of the received 80-samples ST preamble (extracted from the received 160-samples-ST preamble).
The phase angle (`PhiSTDeg`) was -7.5550 degrees at this step taking into account the division of angle by 16.

Similarly, I calculated the phase of the fine CFO using the long training preamble for equation 5 as below:

```
PhiLT= angle( sum( conj(LTS_128_Tx(1:64)) .* LTS_128_Rx_Cor(65:end) ) ) ./64; .......eq5
PhiLTDeg=PhiLT*180/pi
```

The phase angle at this step after dividing the angle by 64 is `PhiLTDeg=-1.7534` which gives a total of phase estimate of -7.5550-1.7534=-9.3084 degrees which far away from my emulated phase shift of -120.
I tried to do equation (5) without dividing the angle by 64 and obtain -112.2159 which gives total phase shift of -7.5550-112.2159=-119.7709 degrees.

Why the proposed equation (5) in the mentioned paper does not give the right answer! Was what I did (writing the code and performing eq.5 without division by 64) correct!
If what I did was correct then why eq.4 was correct with division by 16 and equation 5 was not correct with division by 64!

I have also tried to rewrite the code using the scorr function and the same result mentioned above was obtained:

```
PhiST1=-angle( max(xcorr(STSPreamble_Tx_80(1:64),STSPreamble_Rx_80(17:end))) ) ./16; .....eq4
PhiST1Deg=PhiST1*180/pi
PhiLT1=-angle( max(xcorr(LTS_128_Tx(1:64),LTS_128_Rx_Cor(65:end))) );
PhiLT1Deg=PhiLT1*180/pi
```

Comment: Please learn a little $\LaTeX$ for laying out equations.  That will make your question readable.  And you might want to be explicit in defining ***CFO***.

Comment: Is there anything not clear in my question so I can explain more!

Comment: I would rather not read and decode your MATLAB code.  I would rather want to see it written in mathematical notation that is most consistent with the text of the cited paper that you post as a graphic.   And what does "CFO" mean?  *Coarse Frequency Offset*?  It's in your title and you don't spell out what it is.

Comment: CFO stands for Carrier Frequency Offset.

Comment: For eq. 4, I just assume Sm^* as the conjugate of the known short symbol indicted  from 81 to 144 of the known short Training Preamble (the paper says take the last 5 parts each of 16 sequence which is 80 samples) and multiplied it with the received short training sequence indicted from  97 to 160 samples then I obtain the sum of the product and take the angle.

Comment: Finally I divided the angle by 16 since the shift between the received STS and the known is 16. The result was a small portion of the total phase shift. When I did the same in equation 5, with dividing the angle by 64 it gives a small number and when I add alphaST+alphaLS as the papers says it gives me small values of the total emulated phase shift (-120 degrees).

Comment: Can anyone help me answer my question!